# How do I find missing dates in a list of sorted dates?

Tags: python

In Python how do I find all the missing days in a sorted list of dates?

Comment: What types are your date objects?

Comment: @Mark: The type for date objects is datetime

Answer (score 32, accepted):

using sets

```
>>> from datetime import date, timedelta
>>> d = [date(2010, 2, 23), date(2010, 2, 24), date(2010, 2, 25),
         date(2010, 2, 26), date(2010, 3, 1), date(2010, 3, 2)]
>>> date_set = set(d[0] + timedelta(x) for x in range((d[-1] - d[0]).days))
>>> missing = sorted(date_set - set(d))
>>> missing
[datetime.date(2010, 2, 27), datetime.date(2010, 2, 28)]
>>>
```

Comment: Appreciate your responses, I like this one :) Thanks.

Comment: It took me a minute to realize that was a minus symbol.

Comment: @gwg, ok I added some more whitespace. Better now?

Comment: I guess `sorted` is not needed in  `missing = sorted(date_set - set(d))` as `d` and `date_set` are already sorted

Comment: @abhiieor, not sure what you mean. sets are unordered

Answer (score 4):

Sort the list of dates and iterate over it, remembering the previous entry. If the difference between the previous and current entry is more than one day, you have missing days.

Here's one way to implement it:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
from itertools import tee, izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    b.next()
    return izip(a, b)

def missing_dates(dates):
    for prev, curr in pairwise(sorted(dates)):
        i = prev
        while i + timedelta(1) < curr:
            i += timedelta(1)
            yield i

dates = [ date(2010, 1, 8),
          date(2010, 1, 2),
          date(2010, 1, 5),
          date(2010, 1, 1),
          date(2010, 1, 7) ]

for missing in missing_dates(dates):
    print missing
```

Output:

```
2010-01-03
2010-01-04
2010-01-06
```

Performance is O(n*log(n)) where n is the number of days in the span when the input is unsorted. As your list is already sorted, it will run in O(n).

Comment: @gnibbler: That's great... then this algorithm runs in O(n) time.

Comment: Mine is O(n) too. Had I not used date_set it would have had worst case performance of O(n*n) though :)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> date_list = [datetime(2010, 2, 23),datetime(2010, 2, 24),datetime(2010, 2, 25),datetime(2010, 2, 26),datetime(2010, 3, 1),datetime(2010, 3, 2)]
>>> 
>>> date_set=set(date_list)         # for faster membership tests than list
>>> one_day = timedelta(days=1)
>>> 
>>> test_date = date_list[0]
>>> missing_dates=[]
>>> while test_date < date_list[-1]:
...     if test_date not in date_set:
...         missing_dates.append(test_date)
...     test_date += one_day
... 
>>> print missing_dates
[datetime.datetime(2010, 2, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2010, 2, 28, 0, 0)]
```

This also works for `datetime.date` objects, but the OP says the list is `datetime.datetime` objects

Comment: +1: Seems good. Nice touch with using the parameter name on the timedelta(days=1) for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

**USING A FOR LOOP**

The imports you'll need:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
```

Let's say you have a sorted list called `dates` with several missing dates in it.

First select the first and last date:

```
start_date = dates[0]
end_date = dates[len(dates)-1]
```

Than count the number of days between these two dates:

```
numdays = (end_date - start_date).days
```

Than create a new list with **all** dates between start_date and end_date:

```
all_dates = []
for x in range (0, (numdays+1)):
all_dates.append(start_date + datetime.timedelta(days = x))
```

Than check with dates are in `all_dates` but not in `dates` by using a for loop with range and adding these dates to dates_missing:

```
dates_missing = []

for i in range (0, len(all_dates)):
   if (all_dates[i] not in dates):
       dates_missing.append(all_dates[i])
   else:
       pass
```

Now you'll have a list called `dates_missing` with all the missing dates.

Answer (score 1):

Put the dates in a `set` and then iterate from the first date to the last using `datetime.timedelta()`, checking for containment in the set each time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example for a pandas dataframe with a date column. If it's an index, then change df.Date to df.index.

```
import pandas as pd

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date) # ensure datetime format of date column
min_dt = df.Date.min() # get lowest date
max_dt = df.Date.max() # get highest date

dt_range = pd.date_range(min_dt, max_dt) # get all requisite dates in range
missing_dts = [d for d in dt_range if d not in df.Date] # list missing
print("There are {n} missing dates".format(n=len(missing_dts)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime

DAY = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
# missing dates: a list of [start_date, end)
missing = [(d1+DAY, d2) for d1, d2 in zip(dates, dates[1:]) if (d2 - d1) > DAY]

def date_range(start_date, end, step=DAY):
    d = start_date
    while d < end:
        yield d
        d += step

missing_dates = [d for d1, d2 in missing for d in date_range(d1, d2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension

```
>>> from datetime import date, timedelta
>>> d = [date(2010, 2, 23),date(2010, 2, 24),date(2010, 2, 25),date(2010, 2, 26),date(2010, 3, 1),date(2010, 3, 2)]
>>> date_set=set(d)
>>> missing = [x for x in (d[0]+timedelta(x) for x in range((d[-1]-d[0]).days)) if x not in date_set]

>>> missing
[datetime.date(2010, 2, 27), datetime.date(2010, 2, 28)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way of getting this done in Python is as follows. You need not worry about efficiency unless you have dates from multiple years in your list and this code always needs to run as per user interaction and yield output immediately.

1. Get missing dates from one list (sorted or not)

Create a function that gives you all the dates from `start_date` to `end_date`. And use it.

```
import datetime

def get_dates(start_date, end_date):
    span_between_dates = range(end_date - start_date).days
    for index in span_between_dates + 1:
        # +1 is to make start and end dates inclusive.
        yield start_date + datetime.timedelta(index)

my_date_list = ['2017-03-05', '2017-03_07', ...]
# Edit my_date_list as per your requirement.
start_date = min(my_date_list)
end_date = max(my_date_list)
for current_date in get_dates(start_date, end_date)
    if date not in my_date_list:
        print date
```

2. Get missing or overlapping dates between two date ranges.

`get_dates` function should be defined.

```
my_other_date_list = []  # your other date range
start_date = min(my_date_list)
end_date = max(my_date_list)
for current_date in get_dates(start_date, end_date)
    if (date in my_date_range) and (date in my_other_date_list):
        print ('overlapping dates between 2 lists:')
        print date
    elif (date in my_date_range) and (date not in my_other_date_list):
        print ('missing dates:')
        print date
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have imported the pandas library:

```
incomplete_dates = pd.DataFrame({'dates': ['2021-01-10', '2021-01-14', '2021-01-15','2021-01-20']})

incomplete_dates = pd.to_datetime(incomplete_dates['dates'])

complete_dates = pd.date_range(start="2021-01-10", end="2021-01-20", freq='D')
 
missing_dates = complete_dates.difference(incomplete_dates)

print (missing_dates)
```

```
>>> DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-11', '2021-01-12', '2021-01-13', '2021-01-16',
               '2021-01-17', '2021-01-18', '2021-01-19'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

1. original dataset with missing dates
2. convert string dates into datetime format
3. complete range of time period
4. function for finding missing dates

learn more from:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html